# How to configure rewrite base to support inclusion of php files using htaccess(such as the css script found in a subdir)

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this since i have been going about this for a long time without really understanding what to do when using the .htaccess script for user friendly urls. So the main issue is; the css script in a subdirectory is not accessed by a php script whose main root directory is a subdirectory in the htdocs(web) directory.
Below is the structure of my webdirectory:

I have php website (in development) which I has following structure

```
htdocs
  + myweb.com 
      + assets
         + css
            + style.css
         + includes
            + config.php
      + admin
          + home.php
      + home.php
```

PROBLEM

I am including css in /home.php as ..

```html
    <head>
         <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
```

above is working. Now I wanted same link to be working in /admin/home.php

```html
    <head>
         <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <!-- Not working -->
    </head>                                                     <!-- This wanted -->

    <head>
         <link href="../assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <!-- working -->
    </head>
```

I want a mechanism where file url should start from base. like if I set base to myweb.com, then css inclusion should be valid for /assets/css/style.css in any of file irrespective of location. I tried base rewrite but that is not helping

I tried in .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /myweb.com/
DirectoryIndex home.php  
Platform : XAMPP for windows 64bit..
```

Thank you in advance for your kind consideration.

Answer (score 1):

If your URL doesn't start with `https://` or `/` then it is considered **relative** to the document calling it. So, from a file in the `admin` directory, `assets/css/styles.css` will look for a directory called `assets` and won't find one.

If you want to ensure URLs are always resolved relative to the root, include the root in the URL like so:

```html
<link href="/assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This will work from anywhere, because it is an **absolute** path.

Comment: Thank you @miken32. The issue is, i have my main root as a subroot in the htdocs folder. So using the absolute path "/assets/css/styles.css" refers back to the htdoc web root and obviously that file is not found there. How can i make the reference to the css file to be refered only to the main root(myweb.com; which is a subfolder in the main web folder htdocs).

Comment: You are confusing paths on your file system with your URLs.

Comment: Including the absolute path of the css file alone in the html file does not make any changes could you help me out with this while the reference to the css file using its absolute path do not make any effect

Comment: @user13135530 check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: @CBroe I tried using the <base> tag in the header of my script but to no avail. Its still redirects me to the absolute directory of my webroot which is the htdocs. But the issue is I have a subroot in this absolute webroot(hdoc). So for this website i want the absolute directory to be myweb.com(i.e all redirections  and references to any file should be done here) that is why i used apache mod_rewrite rule of RewritBase /myweb.com/. But this still didn't work. Please I will like someone to clear my doubts on this as this has been taking so much of my time on the project I am working on.

Comment: Setting a RewriteBase on its own doesn’t achieve much. After reading the question again, I am still not sure what actual problem needs solving here? This much more sounds like you should set up a proper virtual host for myweb.com, rather than trying to fix anything later on via rewriting.

Comment: thank you @CBroe i'll do more search on setting a virtual host as i do not know how go about this... I'll do some search here. Thank you guys...